# Need @XMLAttribute with name value even if variable name is same

Tags: jaxb, xjc

please help me out here.
my xsd (only attribute portion not complete)

```
<xs:element name="E1">
   <xs:complextype>
      <xs:attribute name="xyz" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:attribute name="xyz_abc" type="xs:string" />
   </xs:complextype>
</xs:element>
```

produces JAXB class as (again not complete)

```
@XmlAttribute
protected String xyz;

@XmlAttribute(name="xyz_abc")
protected String xyzAbc;
```

but I want the JAXB file to be generated as

```
@XmlAttribute(name="xyz")
protected String xyz;

@XmlAttribute(name="xyz_abc")
protected String xyzAbc;
```

What change I have to make in xsd to generate the desired JAXB class.
I m using maven to generate the JAXB classes.